# Пропали все подсказки в VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

В какой-то момент пропали все подсказки при наборе кода на Python в VSCode.
Что я только не делал, чтобы их вернуть. Переустанавливал расширения, сам vscode и т.д. Ничего не помогает. Подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Прям реально всё переустановили?) В Windows пробовали?

Comment: Попробуйте вспомнить, после каких действий пропали подсказки? может вы что-то настраивали в системе, или что-то загрузили. Т.е. что предшествовало этому.